# Problems using Modernizr with touchscreens

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, modernizr

Since touchscreen devices don't autoplay background videos, I am using Modernizr.js to replace them with background images.

I am targeting them via css with the following code:

```
.no-touch video { display: block }
.touch video { display: none }

.no-touch img { display: none }
.touch img { display: block }
```

In the website I am building, this is working [here](http://bumerangue.pt/index.html) and [here](http://bumerangue.pt/sobre.html). But not in [this page](http://bumerangue.pt/sketches.html). I'm testing it with an iPad and the page background is completely black.

Also, in Chrome, none of the pages work at all.

What could be causing this? Any help is appreciated.